# The meaning of "pros" and "cons"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the exact meaning of "pros" and "cons" in the idiom "the pros and cons of something"? If a "pro" is a professional and  a "con" is someone who committed a crime what do these words refer to in this idiom?

Comment: What happened when you googled ‘pros and cons’? /// From a cursory Google search:  *The phrase ‘pros and cons’ is an abbreviation of the Latin phrase pro et contra, ‘for and against’, and has been in use in the abbreviated form since the 16th century, according to the Oxford English Dictionary.* [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/explore/pros-and-cons-origin)]

Answer (score 4):

Nothing to do with professionals and convicts!!

This is a borrowing from Latin.  A "pro" an advantage or argument in favour of something.  The Latin word *pro* means "for"

And a "con" is an argument against something.  It is shortened from the Latin *contra* meaning against